# How to create scrolling list with picture in Adobe Animate CC/ActionScripts3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animate-cc

I'm a designer and animator, I newly start to coding with Adobe Animate CC, In all versions of adobe flash there is List item but i couldn't find a simple way to add image and text to it, if possible guide me how can i make a scrolling list like below sample image (scroll to receive content from server "like a news app") with simple way not complex coding. I prefer to use Adobe Animate not Adobe FlashBuilder/Flex.

Simple suggestions, Link to tutorial, ...

[image: Sample UI]

Comment: You are advised to make this question more precise. As it stands it is too broad to be considered on topic here. I believe if you just focus on one aspect of your question (i.e. "How do access properties of the List object?") as well as posting the code you have tried, this will be an on topic question then.

Comment: When i don't know true way and related components, I have to ask for what properties of an unknown thing?

Comment: I asked here to someone tell me what is true way, not always questions must be related to codes.

Comment: @NealDavis. Don't try to make this question complex and marvelous, I know there is some component and/or codes to do this but i don't know them, I think experienced developers know them.

Comment: There's no "simple" way. If you prefer Flash IDE then you go the following steps. 1. Create a MovieClip with design (say, image, title, description). 2. Compose an AS3 class that governs its behavior: given the initial data it loads (or otherwise obtains) the image and arranges title and description. 3. Create a scrolling view AS3 class that allows to show as many items as you have and scroll them with touch and drag, and also enables and disables items so only few of them are visible at the same time (performance- and bandwidth- wise).

Comment: The other way is to resort to Flex and MXML, there are List component and you can define custom item renderer (which is basically AS3 class from p.2 above, only in a form of custom MXML component).

Comment: @Organis. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try both way, I have flash builder 4.7 but never used it, is there any way to design UI in Animate CC and add some extra feature like this special list item in FB 4.7?

Comment: Flash IDE has its own palette of components ( e.g. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/List.html ), but unlike Flex they limit you greatly and you cannot do much while customizing them.

Comment: I found the solution in adobe documents: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashcatalyst/cs/using/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-326fcb52123816c0204-7fef.html

Comment: But adobe catalyst discontinued, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look here, you might find what you are looking for. However, if you are just starting to code in AS3, expect to go through some rough spots. 
http://www.myflashlabs.com/product/flash-dynamic-as3-scroller/

This scroller is pretty good, as it works with touch devices, as well as mouse input (desktop). This still requires you to create a movieclip or sprite and attach whatever items to you want to them. Read the documentation and take your time. Best of luck

Comment: It's a good component for static scrolling contents, but its different with my needs.

Comment: I've actually used to scroll dynamic content that gets updated based on user action. It scrolls whatever you throw at it, so if you have movieclips that collect data from the server or what have you, the content will still be updated with using this scroller. At any rate, best wishes to you